# How to test credentials for AWS Command Line Tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

Is there a command/subcommand that can be passed to the `aws` utility that can 1) verify that the credentials in the `~/.aws/credentials` file are valid, and 2) give some indication of which user the credentials belong to? I'm looking for something generic that doesn't make any assumptions about the user have permission to IAM or any specific service.

The use case for this is a deploy-time sanity check to ensure that the credentials are good. Ideally, there would be some way to check the return value and abort the deploy if there are invalid credentials.

Comment: Might I suggest that this would be better asked at http://serverfault.com/?  Stack Overflow is specifically for programming questions.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Yeah, I was on the fence about where to ask. In my mind, the meat of the question was more about programmatically querying an API rather than managing servers per se.

Answer (score 486):

Use [GetCallerIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html):
`aws sts get-caller-identity`

Unlike other API/CLI calls it will always work, regardless of your IAM permissions.

You will get output in the following format:

```
{
    "Account": "123456789012", 
    "UserId": "AR#####:#####", 
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/role-name/role-session-name"
}
```

Exact [ARN format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-iam) will depend on the type of credentials, but often includes the name of the (human) user.

It uses the standard [AWS CLI error codes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/return-codes.html) giving 0 on success and 255 if you have no credentials.

Comment: This is a great answer, but if you are using MFA, look out -- it's more complicated.  With MFA, you need to use working credentials (i) combined with a MFA token to get different working temporary credentials (ii) and with this solution, you get the same results for credentials (i) or (ii).

Comment: @MarkChackerian That's not always the case. I have created a user whose MFA is being enforced using [Trek10's policy](https://www.trek10.com/blog/improving-the-aws-force-mfa-policy-for-IAM-users/). With MFA session token not active, if I execute `aws iam get-user --profile test-mfa`, I get: `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetUser operation`. However, `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile test-mfa` outputs (similarly, with no MFA session token active) the `test-mfa`'s Account, ARN, and the UserId.

Comment: Getting error code 254 (not described in your link) and message `An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCallerIdentity oper
ation: The security token included in the request is invalid.`

Comment: @jangorecki I got that error when my default region wasn't supported (I got a clearer message after trying `aws iam get-user`). After switching my default the suggested command worked properly

Comment: I like this answer. If you find yourself using it regularly, you can make it even easier by creating an alias like this: `alias aws-ping='aws sts get-caller-identity'`. Then you've got an easy command line shorthand.

Answer (score 103):

There is a straightforward way - `aws iam get-user` would tell the details about who you are (the current IAM User) - provided the user has `iam` privileges.

There are couple of CLI calls which support `--dry-run` flag like `aws ec2 run-instances` which you tell you whether you have necessary config / cred to perform the operation.

There is also `--auth-dry-run` which Checks whether you have the required permissions for the command, without actually running the command. If you have the required permissions, the command returns DryRunOperation; otherwise, it returns UnauthorizedOperation. [ From [AWS Documentation - Common Options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/CLTRG-common-args-api.html) ]

You would be able to list the IAM Access Keys from Management Console which you can cross check to see who has been assigned which key.

The best way to understand which user / role has what privileges is make use of [IAM Policy Simulator](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-identity-and-access-management-policy-simulator/).

Comment: Ironically, the user I ran the test as got an `AccessDenied` error -- which included the full `arn:aws:iam::123...890:user/somebody` string as part of the error output.

Comment: Entirely possible the user doesn't have permission to 'get-user' themself. :-/

Comment: Yes, I have this situation. In the AWS Console next to User ARN it shows N/A, and the hover over explains that "User arn:aws:iam:...:user/steve is not authorized to perform iam:GetUser on resource: user steve"

Answer (score 0):

I was in need of the same so I wrote [`aws-role`](https://github.com/Grijesh-Chauhan/recipes/tree/main/aws-role)

I also wanted that the command outputs session time remains before logout:

[image]

I used it in many shell scripts to automate my AWS use -- worked well for me.

my script parse `~/.aws/credentials`

<sub>PS: also thinking to enhance it to support JSON output</sub>