# How do I find out which user a given AWS Access Key Id goes to?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-iam

I have several AWS keys floating around. Currently in `C:\users\chloe\.aws\credentials` I have an `aws_access_key_id` with lowercase letters (more recent keys seem to be uppercase) and which does not start with `AKIA...`. How do I find out the user and role to that key? I tried running

```
>aws iam get-user

An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetUser operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

But I always get an error. I tried changing `region` in `C:\users\chloe\.aws\config` to various regions, but still get the same error. (Not sure why the region is specified in a different file from the keys.) I've tried running `aws configure` and it gives me the prompt for the key, secret, region, and output with the first 3 filled out (starred out keys).

Unrelated: [Given an AWS Access / Secret Key Pair, how do I retrieve its IAM permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401632/given-an-aws-access-secret-key-pair-how-do-i-retrieve-its-iam-permissions)

Comment: Not `AKIA`?  What are the first 4?  `ASIA`?  Something else?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes the first 4 characters are something else... `7g...`

Comment: Then that is probably a Secret Key (like a password), not an Access Key.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No because the secret key is on the line below, and longer.

Comment: An AWS Access Key will always start with `AKIA` or `ASIA`.